# Проверка на точное совпадение mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть  ячейка **"users"**, которая содержит **"1,2,3,4,5"**.  Как проверить  Через **SELECT**, есть ли в этой ячейке цифра **2**, например?

Такой вариант не работает:

```
$user = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='1' AND users like '%2'");
if ($user->num_rows) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Так как он считает **22** и **202** за то, что мне нужно (2).

Или такие вещи нужно проверять через php регулярками? Или для такого нужно создаавать   отдельную таблицу? Подскажите, как лучше, заранее, спасибо.

Comment: А на уровне проектирования структуры БД решить не вариант?

Comment: $user = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='1' AND users ='2' ");

Comment: @Bloom это  не   работает, потому что ячейка содержит не одно число

Comment: она не должна содержать "не одно число". это **ячейка**, а не колхоз. поэтому да, надо создавать отдельную таблицу

Comment: $arr[]=$row['name']; $key=array_search('2', $arr); if($key!=''){ echo 'что то нашлось';}

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', users)`.

Comment: @Akira благодарю.